# Function and inner function same arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino

Could somebody please help me how to achieve that my function accepts only that argument types that the function can be called inside it?

I have a Logger class what can be started with a `HardwareSerial` object in in the `setup()` function of an Arduino code.
Then in the `loop()` I would like to call the `Logger.print()` function that should accepts only that arguments what `HardwareSerial.print()` can be called.

Here is my ugly and not working tries:

```
template <typename... ARGS>
size_t print(const ARGS &... args) {
    if (serial != NULL) {
        if (sizeof...(args) == 2) {
            return this->serial->print(args[0], args[1]);
        } else if (sizeof...(args) == 1) {
            return this->serial->print(args[0]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
size_t print(const T &t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<const __FlashStringHelper *, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_base_of<const String &, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_array<T>::value ||
                                                     //std::is_same<char[std::extent<T>::value], T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<char, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<char *, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<const char *, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<unsigned char, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<int, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<unsigned int, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<long, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<unsigned long, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_same<double, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_convertible<const Printable &, T>::value ||
                                                     std::is_convertible<struct tm *, T>::value,
                                                 T>::type * = 0) {
    if (serial != NULL) {
        return this->serial->print(t);
    }
    retrun 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting whether a function can be called is a piece of cake when you use `decltype` for the SFINAE check:

```
template <typename... ARGS>
auto print(const ARGS &... args) -> decltype(this->serial->print(args...)) {
    if (serial != NULL) {
        return this->serial->print(args...);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for variadic template expension is

```
template <typename... ARGS>
size_t print(const ARGS&... args) {
    if (serial != nullptr) {
        return this->serial->print(args...);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to make it SFINAE friendly, you might use:

```
template <typename... ARGS>
auto print(const ARGS&... args) -> decltype(this->serial->print(args...))
{
    if (serial != nullptr) {
        return this->serial->print(args...);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the same interface as `HardwareSerial`, with all the `print`, `println` and `write` methods, your `Logger` class should inherit from `Print` and then only implement the `write(uint8_t)` method that only calls `HardwareSerial`s `write(uint8_t)`.

```
class Logger : public Print {
    public:
        virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
}
```

```
size_t Logger::write(uint8_t c) {
    if (this->serial != NULL) {
       return this->serial->write(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More on `Print` class: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Printclass